How do I reduce the time taken for the insertion of a dataframe in a large table of a database in SQL Server?
Overview
I need to update the data in a database owned by me with data which is fetched from a Snowflake server DB. I fetch data for a particular date from Snowflake and need to insert that in a local database for that date. This operation currently takes 273 s and I need to optimize it as much as possible. All of this is done in Python using the pyodbc library for insertion in the local database and sqlalchemy to fetch the data from Snowflake.
Detailed Process
I am using cProfile in combination with Snakeviz to profile and visualize the performance of my operation which runs for a particular date called update_snf. The whole process consists of the following steps:

Creating a connection and running an SQL query to fetch data from the Snowflake server. Call this operation get_data_from_snf. It is taking 111 s to perform this operation with the majority (108 s) of the time taken by the Pandas.read_sql(query, connection) function call (defined in pandas/io/sql.py) which executes the query and returns the result in a dataframe df.
Formatting df, which takes relatively less time (17.8 s)
Inserting the formatted dataframe df in my local database (call this function insert_data_into_db). This operation takes the majority of the time (143 s out of which 93.1 s is taken by the executemany method of the pyodbc.Cursor object and 43.3 s by the execute method). Let us call the table where this insertion happens table. table is a fairly large table with approximately 150 million tuples and 130 columns.

I am trying to reduce the time for this entire operation in any way possible, by optimizing any or even all of the steps. df is expected to contain around 200,000 rows for each date.
Current Attempt
Fairly basic Python APIs are being used and no multiprocessing or multithreading is being used at the moment. The insertion of data in a very large table was taking unacceptable amount of time so an alternative is being used currently which implements insert_data_into_db as follows:

A new table is created called table_temp (this table already exists in the database; it is not created afresh every time the function is run)
cursor.execute is used to execute the following SQL query:

TRUNCATE TABLE table_temp
DELETE FROM table where Date = {date}

The delete operation is necessary to ensure that only the updated entries from Snowflake are present in the local server and there is no duplication. It basically removes outdated data before fresh data can be inserted back.

df is split into chunks of 18000 rows and cursor.fast_executemany is set to True. We now use cursor.executemany(insert_query, df_chunk) to insert each of the chunks (a list of tuples) one-by-one into table_temp.

We now insert the entire table_temp (which contains all the entries for the particular date from Snowflake) into table using:


INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM table_temp

So instead of inserting data directly into table, we first insert it in chunks into a temporary table and then insert the entire temporary table into table.
The questions in this current approach are:

Is there any way to avoid this chunking approach and directly insert into table which doesn't take too much time? It seems like the time taken for this direct insertion increases as table becomes larger and at the current size of 150 million rows, it seems to take too much time.
Can we use parallelism in the form of multiprocessing or multithreading anywhere in this approach?
Can we use streaming somewhere over here? If yes, how?
Can we speed up the fetching of data from Snowflake into a Dataframe in memory before inserting the Dataframe into the database? Is there any way to avoid this altogether?

tl;dr
I want to reduce the time it takes to fetch data from a DB on Snowflake and insert it into a local DB.
I am using Python 3.11 on a Windows 8 server using SQL Server. Any optimizations are welcome! Thanks a lot!

one thing you can do to increase the speed is database normalization. it is something basic  and might not even increase it that much and this is probably already done in your database besides that it is still something you can look into

@kaddy , I would like to give suggestion on bullet point 2, if you can focus on multiprocessing using python multi-process package library ,i believe this data copying from Snowflake and inserting into Sql server can let to you to speed up the overall process. Snowflake has option of Copy Into command which copies data from Snowflake to external stage such as Azure blob or AWS bucket has inbuilt mechanism to copy data in parallel but then you have to bring the data from that external storage back into SQL Server, not sure how this would work in terms of performance.

@akshindesnowflake I have faced problems while trying multiprocessing to insert data for multiple dates. The update_snf function as I am describing above runs for a single date and to run it for multiple dates, I tried to call the update_snf function in multiple processes using the Pool API provided by multiprocessing.  However, this led to some undiagnosed duplication issues where duplicate data was inserted into table. I am not sure if SQL server allows multiple cursors to insert safely at the same time but due to the duplication, I am a little averse to using something like this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Added a tl;dr to highlight what exactly I need
